# Check if an element that is inside multiple scrollable containers is visible to the user

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am wondering if there is a way (either in pure javascript or with jQuery, or with any other javascript library) to determine whether a html element that is contained within multiple nested scrollable containers is actually visible to the user.

Suppouse I want to determine whether the red "li" (item 4) on this example page: http://kamilkp.co.nf/scrollable/
can be seen by the user.

I have searched the web, but the only solutions I found work for an element inside a single scrollable element, i.e. body.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: sure you could calculate it...what did you try? The point of this site is you post your efforts, point out where your problems are....we help.

Comment: I thought that jQuery .position() function would give me the distance in pixels from an element to it's parent left/top bound, but it turns out it calculates the distances to it's offsetParent (first absolutely/relatively/fixed positioned parent). And i stopped at that point. Also I was hoping that maybe someone has come across the same problem before and has got the solution.

Comment: depending on css at play in page...could set position relative where needed and start working up the parents doing calcs

Comment: Modyfing any of the css properties of existing html elements is out of the question. I think i'm gonna have to calculate offsets and scroll positions.